# Convert json array to object array in typescript

Tags: arrays, json, typescript, type-conversion, angular5

I have array of type json I want it to convert in object type array

**JSON array**

```
[  
0:{code: "00125", scheme: "0001", plotNumber: "125", propType: "001", plotType: "001", }
1:{code: "190", scheme: "0001", plotNumber: "NA 190", propType: "001", plotType: "001"}
2:{code: "210", scheme: "0001", plotNumber: "NA210", propType: "001", plotType: "001"}
]
```

Want to convert to **object array** like this

```
 [
{code: "00125", scheme: "0001", plotNumber: "125", propType: "001", plotType: "001" },
    {code: "190", scheme: "0001", plotNumber: "NA 190", propType: "001", plotType: "001"},
    {code: "210", scheme: "0001", plotNumber: "NA210", propType: "001", plotType: "001"}
    ]
```

Comment: This is not a question. This is a work assignment. Don't post work assignments on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Dear i'm looking for a function or library here to convert json type to object

Comment: I'm using push method which is adding index to new object

Comment: You`ve got two arrays here, you don't neet to convert one into the other. Yes, in the rerpesentation of the second array you're omitting the indexes, but they are still there. Without indexes, how would you access the second element of the array, for example?

Answer (score 4):

This Array

```
[  
   0:{code: "00125", scheme: "0001", plotNumber: "125", propType: "001", plotType: "001", }
   1:{code: "190", scheme: "0001", plotNumber: "NA 190", propType: "001", plotType: "001"}
   2:{code: "210", scheme: "0001", plotNumber: "NA210", propType: "001", plotType: "001"}
]
```

is not a JSON. And so you can't convert it. If it was a JSON it would look like this:

```
[  
   {"code": "00125", "scheme": "0001", "plotNumber": "125", "propType": "001", "plotType": "001" },
   {"code": "190", "scheme": "0001", "plotNumber": "NA 190", "propType": "001", "plotType": "001"}, 
   ...
]
```

Where do you get it from as you are of the opinion that it ought to be a JSON? Or is this just an example you've written manually?

If you have a real JSON-string and you want to convert it back into an object do it like this:

```
let myObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

And the other way around:

```
let jsonString = JSON.stringify(myObject);
```